# C# - use symbols from other class without qualifying with classname

Tags: c#

I have declared a bunch of global constants in a class and now want to use these constants in other classes without always having to prefix the constants with the name of the class they have been declared in. Example:

```
namespace SomeName
{
   public class Constants
   {
      public const int SomeConstant = 1;
   }

   public class SomeClass
   {
      void SomeFunc ()
      {
         int i = Constants.SomeConstant;
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to omit `Constants.` from `Constants.SomeConstant`. Using `import SomeName.Constants;` didn't work. Is there a way to accomplish what I want? If yes, how would I do it?

Comment: What is the motivation for this? It sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @BrokenGlass importing a class like `Math` this way shortens mathematical code a bit and IMO makes it easier to read. Unfortunately I know of no way to do this in C#.

Comment: BrokenGlass, you should probably share your insight with the C# specification and development teams, who have made this possible for all the C# system libraries - probably they have made a grave mistake here, or didn't they? No, the reason I want that is that I am having a bunch of global constants in my app and don't want to have to prefix them with their class name throughout the entire app. From a point of reading and understanding the source code that is completely superfluous in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way you can do that.

Having read your comment (*"...importing a class like Math this way shortens mathematical code a bit"*) I can suggest this wicked code:

```
class MathCalculations
{
    private Func<double, double, double> min = Math.Min;
    private Func<double, double, double> max = Math.Max;
    private Func<double, double> sin = Math.Sin;
    private Func<double, double> tanh = Math.Tanh;

    void DoCalculations()
    {
        var r = min(max(sin(3), sin(5)), tanh(40));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh the pain ... I was afraid of that answer ... :(

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is use a very short [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx):

```
using C = Constants;

C.SomeContant;
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Maybe you mean `using C = Constants;`?

Comment: Thanks, but if that's the only way to come close to what I am looking for, I think it's better to use the full name of the actual source class in order to avoid obscuring the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using inheritance (which is a *really* bad idea; don't do it) there's no way of doing this. (In particular, if you were thinking of trying a using directive alias, that can only alias a namespace or a *type*, not the *member* of a type.)

As Oded points out, you can reduce the "Constants" to "C", but personally I wouldn't.

Comment: LOL - I know I *really* shouldn't use inheritance for that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with skeet, but you could:

1) Create a static class

```
public static class Constants{
    public static const int SomeConstant = 1;
}
```

2) Add a struct property to SomeClass

```
public struct Constants{
    public const int SomeConst = 1;
}
```

Both of these will allow you to have the same code in the SomeFunc() method and allow the code to be easily maintained.

Comment: 2) Doesn't make sense for me since I need the constants in a bunch of other classes. 1) Doesn't seem to work - I still have to write "Constants.SomeConstant" (or I haven't really understood that proposition of yours).